# Is "me gustas" ever correct, e.g. to say "I like you"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales

We have been taught that 'gustar' is an unusual verb and that you only ever use 'gusta' or 'gustan' depending on whether you like singular or plural things.

Would you use 'me gustas' to say 'I like you'?

Comment: Note that in at least some dialects of Spanish as it is spoken (as opposed to Spanish as the academies say it should be spoken) *gustar* is used as *like* - e.g. *¿Gustas el café?*.

Comment: It's always right when you like someone but not something (i.e. "I like it" it's not "Me gustas" but "Me gusta")

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Which dialects? Would they be ones very close to Portugese regions? I ask because Portuguese *gostar* works like English *like* and not like Spanish *gustar* even though they are clearly close cognates.

Comment: @César: Actually you could use *me gustas* with anything you address. So yes usually a person but also could involve personification of say a pet or robot but perhaps even inanimate objects on objects on occasion, in which case it would be just as quirky as in English telling your car or computer that you like it.

Comment: @David: Look no further than the famous Manu Chao song, ***[Me Gustas Tú](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzgjiPBCsss)***!

Comment: @hippietrail, I've heard it in México, but I don't know whether it's widely used there or just in or around Jalisco.

Comment: *gustar* is not unusual at all. It's almost equivalent to the verb *like*.  And *me gustas* is correct and very common, I've actually told *me gustas* to many girls ;-)

Comment: Gustar is a verb like "belong" in English, where the thing being liked is the subject, not the object, and the verb is conjugated in consequence. "Tú gustas a mí"->"Tú me gustas". "Vosotros gustáis a mí" -> "Vosotros me gustáis". Just like in German: "Das gefällt mir" -> "Mir gefällt das".

Please read this related question http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/why-a-ti-and-not-just-ti.

Comment: @PeterTaylor *gustás el café* is absolutely accepted by the academies, see my answer.

Comment: I have been taught for years that "me gustas" means "You like me" and been told this is a regional use of the form and definition. Huge debate in my class.

Comment: Me gustas=I like you. You like me=te gusto a ti.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, *me gustas* is correct way to say this.

*Gustar* is "unusual" in the way that it doesn't mean "to like", but rather "to be liked by".  "to please"

It's absolutely not true that you only ever use *gusta* or *gustan*.

Consider few examples for each grammatical person:

> Ya no te gusto — You don't like me anymore
>
> Me gustas — I like you
>
> Me gusta España — I like Spain
>
> Sé que os gustamos — I know that you like us
>
> No me gustáis — I don't like you *(plural)*
>
> No me gustan los toros — I don't like bullfighting

Comment: I should probably have said "normally only use". Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Even in normal common usage it's not limited to these two cases.

Comment: I would say *gustar* is only unusual when compared to English *to like*. Taken on its own it's perfectly usual. After all English *to please* works the same way and we wouldn't say it is unusual.

Comment: It's also unusual in that the subject nearly always comes after the verb and not before. This is still grammatical Spanish, but [S]VO is a more common order.

Comment: Is this true for "encantar" as well??

Comment: "encantar", I'm no native speaker, yes ... but that would mean really strong feelings, like "love".

Comment: No me gustáis — for Spanish not Latinos

Answer (score 29):

A remark regarding usage. I'm not very sure what you mean exactly by `I like you` in English (from a person to another). But in Spanish, if you say `me gustas`, this is in a more-than-friends sense. In a *just-as-friends* context, it's better to use `me caes bien` or `me agradas`. I think `me gustas` is more like `I have a little crush on you`. Be careful with that.

Comment: Totally agree +1.

Comment: Great point! +1

Comment: In Mexico, at least, it's actually stronger than a little crush.  It is quite possible for this to be taken as an out and out come-on.

Answer (score 16):

As @vartec said, `me gustas` is correct. A great way to think about gustar in English is to imagine a word *gust* that means the opposite of disgust. Just like you would say `that person disgusts me,` with this imaginary word *gust*, you would say `that person gusts me,` meaning he or she pleases you, the opposite of disgust.

Or, for the case is question, `you gust me,` which would then translate back to `me gustas`.

Read more at [thelearninglight.com](http://www.thelearninglight.com/gustar.htm).

Comment: +1 interesting indeed!

Comment: You beat me to it. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=disgust&searchmode=none

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have focused on using *gustar* in the structure that it's normally taught in Spanish classes where *gustar takes an indirect object pronoun.  While the most *common* use is absolutely either *gusta* or *gustan* (see [this Google N-Gram](http://me%20gusta+te%20gusta+le%20gusta+les%20gusta+nos%20gusta+os%20gusta,me%20gustan+te%20gustan+le%20gustan+les%20gustan+nos%20gustan+os%20gustan,me%20gustas+le%20gustas+les%20gustas+nos%20gustas,me%20gust%C3%A1is,te%20gusto+le%20gusto+les%20gusto,le%20gustamos+les%20gustamos), I omitted valid forms that weren't found so I could fit it all in a single search), the other forms, as you can see, are certainly used.

There is also another way to use *gustar* that mirrors the English construction a bit more closely (and is identical to modern Portuguese), although it will come off very formal in modern Spanish.  See the comparison:

- I like pizza a lot.
  Me gusta mucho la pizza. <sub>(standard)</sub>
  **Gusto** mucho *de* la pizza. <sub>(alternate)</sub>
- We like to read.
  Nos gusta leer.
  **Gustamos** *de* leer.
- You're into me.
  Te gusto.
  **Gustas** de mí.

To use this structure, you use *gustar* with the same subject you would in the English statement, and follow it with the preposition *de*.  The thing that is liked is the object of that preposition.

Finally, *gustar* can be used to mean *like/wish/want/prefer* and in this case it is actually a transitive verb, as in *¿Gusta Vd. un vino tinto?* <sub>(would you like a red wine?)</sub> or *Haz como gustes* <sub>(do as you will/wish)</sub>.  This usage is very rare outside of, well, basically the two phrases (with minimal variation for subject/object) I gave ;-)

Comment: gusto mucho de la pizza??

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to user0721090601's answer, stating that the normal use of "gustar" as a transitive verb has the subject as the cause of pleasure or attraction, I give you here - from the Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas (2010) - that

> Esta es la construcción normal en el habla corriente.

The alternate construction may be found mostly in writing, as I highlight below, and in this case, "de" should **not** be omitted:

> **gustar. 1.** Cuando significa ‘causar, o sentir, placer o atracción’ es intransitivo y puede construirse de dos formas:
>
> **a)** El sujeto es la causa del placer o la atracción, y la persona que lo siente se expresa mediante un complemento indirecto: «Vos me gustás mucho» (Rovner Pareja [Arg. 1976]); «Le gustaban la buena música y los buenos libros» (Palou Carne [Esp. 1975]). **Esta es la construcción normal en el habla corriente.**
>
> **b)** La persona que siente el placer es el sujeto y aquello que lo causa se expresa mediante un complemento introducido por de: «Gustaba de reunirse con amigos en su casa» (UPietri Oficio [Ven. 1976]). Es construcción **documentada sobre todo en la lengua escrita.** Debe evitarse la omisión de la preposición de, frecuente cuando el complemento regido es un infinitivo: «Barcelona y Tenerife, dos conjuntos que gustan jugar al ataque» (Vanguardia [Esp.] 22.3.94).
>
> **2**. Como transitivo significa ‘querer o desear’ y su empleo es escaso fuera de fórmulas de cortesía: «¿Gusta usted una cerveza?» (Victoria Casta [Méx. 1995]); «—¿Le molesto si escucho las noticias? —Haga como guste» (Plaza Cerrazón [Ur. 1980]).

Answer (score -4):

No, it is not correct.  At least not grammatically correct.  While it may be accepted in casual conversation, gustar is conjugated with either a singular or a plural ending.  The person is not doing the action, rather represents a single noun that has an effect on a person.  ie.  Juan a mí me gusta.  or  Tû a mí me gusta.   In this case, the subject pronoun 'you' is not doing the action, therefore the second person tense is not employed.  Rather, another item, a singular noun, which happens to be a person, is having an effect on a person.  It's comparable to saying that person makes me .... If you require more explanation, look in 501 verbs.  It's a great resource.  Thanks.
Buena suerte.

Comment: "Me gustas" is perfectly valid. You could say "A mi me gusta Juan" (native speakers would favor that structure over "Juan a mí me gusta"). If you were talking to Juan then you could tell him "_Me gustas_, Juan". "Tû a mí me gusta" is incorrect. Conjugation should be ["gusta**s**"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=ECUfD8eYcVcRj3FxGuHC).

Comment: In addition to what @Diego said, there are some terminology issues here.  There are no conjugations that aren't singular or plural, so to imply a verb can "only" be conjugated in singular/plural says only that it's not a defective verb.  Subject *pronouns* don't do actions, just the subjects.  There is no "second person tense", tenses indicate temporality, being second person (of which there are 4-5 conjugations for gustar in each tense).

Comment: Also, when I say "algo me gusta", that thing *is* doing the action — it just happens the most adequate translation into English switches the roles.  Both languages have ways of structuring utterances such that the liked thing is subject or object: I like something, something pleases me, me gusta algo, prefiero algo (or even gusto de algo)

Comment: @user0721090601 This is late, I know, but https://books.google.cl/books?id=maz9oLIKZKkC&pg=PT90&lpg=PT90&dq=%22it+likes+me%22+or+%22i+like+it%22&source=bl&ots=ppLbQTiXTO&sig=ACfU3U06T8gWMQKH-xyc-ixxzfjGTovX_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAisnehfvoAhVKH7kGHdypCNcQ6AEwBnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22it%20likes%20me%22%20or%20%22i%20like%20it%22&f=false suggests that English was once the other way- something liking you meant that it pleased you.